# redefine shortcuts for keys being set to default after reboot

Tags: shortcut-keys

i am using PHPStorm editor on Ubuntu 14.04. Everything is so smooth that I am loving the experience (especially the workspace experience is amazing)

however this bug is giving me headache... some of the editor's short-cuts clash with default Ubuntu keys (Alt + Ctrl + Left,Right,Up or Down arrow keys). I have changed the default keys to (super + Left,Right,Up and Down arrow keys) so they don't collide with my editor but after the reboot, Ubuntu changes are somehow reverting to default.

This keeps comming again and again. i am sure there is a way out so therefore need help with that...

Answer (score 0):

You can define/unset shortcuts programmatically, use dconf in CLI mode as explained [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461921/how-do-i-reset-unity-default-shortcuts)

Example :

```
# remove annoying ubuntu shortcuts
dconf write "/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-right" "['']"
dconf write "/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-left" "['']"
dconf write "/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-top" "['']"
dconf write "/org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings/switch-to-workspace-down" "['']"
```

Execute these commands at startup