# How do I reset Unity default shortcuts?

Tags: unity, 14.04, shortcuts, reset

How do I reset the default value of Unity shortcut?

In: "System Settings -▸ Keyboard -▸ Shortcuts ..."

For instances:

- I can't put the default <kbd>Alt L</kbd> for the HUD.
- I can't put the default <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Print</kbd> to capture the active window.

Simply typing it doesn't work.

Solving this in CLI is preferable.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Through GUI:**

1. Install `dconf-editor`

   ```
   sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
   ```
2. Follow paths one by one, Click `Set Default` button on bottom right edge.

   ```
   /org/compiz/integrated/show-hud
   /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/window-screenshot
   ```

**Using CLI:**

```
dconf reset /org/compiz/integrated/show-hud
dconf reset /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/window-screenshot
```

**References:**

- [`man dconf`](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/dconf.1.html)
- A hint to get where any shortcut is stored, use `dconf watch /` Then try changing them from System Settings → Keyboard → Shortcuts
- Use `-f` option to reset a path or directory at once, example:

  ```
  dconf reset -f /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/
  ```

BTW, for HUD the default shortcut is `Alt L`, which is the Left Alt, not `Alt+L`.

Comment: dconf-editor's allready installed.
FYI, in the first post before v2r edit it, it was Alt L and not Alt + L.........
EDIT: It works thanks a lot, I was tiping those command in root...

Comment: @user278729, sure about cli?

Comment: I realized I have to type these without root priviledge..., solve.

Comment: In **Ubuntu-gnome-16.04** it was under `org -> gnome -> desktop -> wm -> keybindings`