# how reset keyboard binding ubuntu 15.04 to defalut on lenovo k2450?

Tags: unity, 15.04, shortcut-keys, laptop

how to reset keyboard key binding (shortcut) set default? i mess up with keyboard shortcut key fn + volume up and key fn + volume down before work wells before i mess up :P

Answer (score 0):

one way is to click the dashboard, type keyboard, then select shortcuts tab. In left pane go to sound and media.

There you can see what is the current shortcut for volume down , volume up. To change these shortcuts, select the appropriate choice with mouse, it will change to "New accelerator" and then you can press the keys you want to select in your case fn +  volume up and fn + volume down.

Alternative have a look at these [link1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/17626/how-can-i-restore-default-keyboard-shortcuts) , [link2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461921/how-do-i-reset-unity-default-shortcuts)