# How to reset default shortcuts for Ubuntu 15.10 (Macbook Pro Late 2013)

Tags: 14.04, unity, keyboard, shortcut-keys, 15.10

**How can I reset the keyboard shortcuts back to defaults?**

I have installed Ubuntu 15.10 on a MackBook Pro Late 2013. If there is any other specifics you need from me to assist, please let me know and I will update the question.

> Note: I am brand new to Linux. This is my first installation.

I began updating some of the keyboard shortcuts to be more in-line with what I am used to on my MacBook Pro. This quickly became more cumbersome then I would have liked, as there are conflicting shortcuts etc.

Comment: I found a suggestion from an [link](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1126948) on older forum post found here that suggest loading the live CD or USB drive and copying the shortcuts you want to revert manually. This may help some if you remember which shortcuts you updated. In my case I updated quite a few and didn't take note so I am still searching for a reset all kind of solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I followed the steps from [How do I reset Unity default shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461921/how-do-i-reset-unity-default-shortcuts) since that referenced 14.04 which was the most recent version I could find an answer to.

1) I had to install dconf-editor since that was not yet installed.

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

2) Run the dconf-editor

```
dconf-editor
```

3) Once I launched the editor as the post suggested I followed these two paths:

```
/org/compiz/integrated/show-hud
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/window-screenshot
```

Within the editor in both of these areas I noticed that several of the items were **bolded** thankfully the system was showing me which ones I had changed.

Example: "Screenshot"
[image]

Once you select the name you can select the "set to default" button in the bottom right of the window.

[image]

While I would love to find a **reset all** option. This has worked out great and everything is back to defaults. I actually feel comfortable editing them again knowing it keeps track of the changed items.