# Unable to type $ symbol in Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I am unable to type the dollar sign ($) using Shift+4 combo in Ubuntu. Nothing happens when this combo is pressed.
The issue was first noticed in 16.04, and continues after upgrade to 17.04.
As this is a dual boot Ubuntu and is not frequently used for programming, this issue was noticed only recently. Hence I cannot remember if any new app caused this issue.

Some more details regarding the system and debugging:

- The laptop has a standard keyboard (no special currency symbols etc), with keyboard layout set as US in Ubuntu.
- Shift key, and 4 key works individually. Shift+3, Shift+5 combos work correctly.
- Shift+4 combo works correctly while booted to Windows, and $ sign appears correctly.
- Tried typing $ sign with on-screen keyboard in Ubuntu (on-board), but nothing happens when I click on Shift key and then the 4 key.
- Can type $ using unicode (Ctrl+Shift+U 0024) in Ubuntu

It would be really helpful if anyone can provide directions on how I can debug this issue or info on any known app causing this.

xev output for Shift+3:

```
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x20a, subw 0x0, time 386927, (870,72), root:(870,124),
    state 0x10, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x20a, subw 0x0, time 387092, (870,72), root:(870,124),
    state 0x11, keycode 12 (keysym 0x23, numbersign), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (23) "#"
    XmbLookupString gives 1 bytes: (23) "#"
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x20a, subw 0x0, time 387208, (870,72), root:(870,124),
    state 0x11, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x20a, subw 0x0, time 387224, (870,72), root:(870,124),
    state 0x10, keycode 12 (keysym 0x33, 3), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (33) "3"
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

xev output for Shift+4:

```
KeyPress event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x20a, subw 0x0, time 607916, (648,613), root:(648,665),
    state 0x10, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XmbLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False

KeymapNotify event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x0,
    keys:  10  0   0   0   0   0   4   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   
           0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   

KeyRelease event, serial 28, synthetic NO, window 0x4000001,
    root 0x20a, subw 0x0, time 608219, (648,613), root:(648,665),
    state 0x11, keycode 50 (keysym 0xffe1, Shift_L), same_screen YES,
    XLookupString gives 0 bytes: 
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Comment: By any chance is Shift+$ or 4 bound to any other shortcut, you can check from System Settings/Keyboard ? Do you have a different profile for shortcuts or have you changed any shortcuts ?

Comment: I have checked all existing shortcuts in Keyboard settings, but nothing is mapped to Shift+4

Comment: anything with Shift+$ ? maybe try resetting the keyboard shortcuts to default and see if it works

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/461921/how-do-i-reset-unity-default-shortcuts  ...  for resetting keyboard shortcuts

Comment: There is no shortcut for Shift+$ as well. I tried resetting key bindings for org/gnome/desktop/wm/keybindings, but the issue is still there.

Comment: I am out of ideas :( ...  Go to System Settings/Text Entry , choose your input source (English US) and then press the keyboard icon (out of 3 icons below source selection pane) ... Now try Shift+4 ... are they both getting pressed? the pressed keys will be highlighted in a visual keyboard on screen

Comment: Maybe `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-configuration` and reboot might help ... as you said that it has never come to your notice since installation, the default keyboard configuration for ubuntu might not be appropriate for your hardware ... but before this check if Shift+4 are pressed simultaneously (highlighted in visual keyboard) as mentioned in above comment

Comment: @Suparshva In the Text Entry view, pressing Shift highlights the key, but then pressing 4 after it doesn't highlight 4; this also removes highlight from Shift key. I have added output from `xev` in the question. The Shift+4 combo is resulting in a keymap event, although I don't understand where this is configured. I am using an Asus ROG laptop, and tried dpkg reconfigure to choose 'Asus Laptop' option. This isn't solving the issue.

Comment: Perhaps you could try ALT-GR and 4 ... ?  (ALT-GR is the ALT-key to the right of the space-bar) This is the combination used on scandinavian keyboards among others...

Comment: Try switching your language layout. What layout do you have right now ?

Comment: By chance when you use `shift`+`4` does `dmesg | tail` report an error message?

Comment: I think most probably the problem is with the keyboard configuration ... I saw the keyboards of some models of Asus ROG and they are very fancy, I wonder those fancy keys are working correctly, are they? ... I can't tell what configuration might work for sure for your particular device ... As Sergiy said, try changing layout other than what  you currently have and see if it changes something ...

Comment: Also I would like you to install `dconf-editor` and run it ... go to desktop/ibus/general and tell what do you observe?

Comment: Try with external USB keyboard if you can ... this can confirm problem with the configuration particularly for your keyboard and not something else ... For USB keyboard you might need to reconfigure

Comment: Thanks everyone for the new suggestions. I tried out Ubuntu 17.04 from a live USB and it had no issues typing $ symbol. So I did a fresh install and everything seems fine. 
My keyboard layout is detected as US layout and it really doesn't have any fancy keys other than the usual function keys. But I will now keep a close check on if any new software is causing the issue again, and update this thread.