# "Fn" key + Keyboard shortcuts

Tags: shortcut-keys, function-keys

I don't know how to disable the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key and in the process messed up my keyboard shortcuts, I am mainly looking for a way to return them to default. I use Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and I use a Microsoft All-In-One Media Keyboard (N9Z-00022).

Answer (score 1):

You can check **System Settings → Keyboard** and go to the Shortcuts tab. I'm not sure about the particular settings for your system but I think the <kbd>Fn</kbd> key works on a firmware level. It doesn't have much to do with the OS you are using. To disable it you might have to enter the BIOS of your system and disable it. Going through other similar questions, I read that pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>ESC</kbd> will enable/disable the <kbd>Fn</kbd> functions. If that doesn't work, try <kbd>Fn</kbd>+<kbd>Super</kbd>+<kbd>Esc</kbd>. To restore default shortcuts, you would have to use dconf-editor.

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-editor
```

Follow paths one by one, Click Set Default button on bottom right edge.

```
/org/compiz/integrated/show-hud
/org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/window-screenshot
```

Source: [How do I reset Unity default shortcuts?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/461921/how-do-i-reset-unity-default-shortcuts)

Comment: Thank you so much, the key combination to disable/invert the Fn key didn't work though.